# R studio no memory available

Tags: r, memory, rstudio

I was doing some analyses in R studio and up to now everything worked fine. Out of a sudden however I'm getting the error message

> no memory available

and can't do certain computations anymore (which worked fine beforehand).

Does anyone know this problem, respectively how to solve it?

Comment: Does it actually say "no memory available" or are you paraphrasing? I have a feeling it says "Error: cannot allocate vector of size ___" or "In '... ' reached total allocation of ___", in which case this question is a duplicate. Change the memory limit, use 64-bit R, and/or use tips from the highly upvoted R memory management thread to manage memory better.

Comment: No it is saying exactly this: "Error in logistf.fit(x = x, y = y, weight = weight, offset = offset, firth,  : 
  no memory available"   ...my memory limit is at 16247 and I'm already using 64-bit R... I'll check the memory management thread again but if I remember right I couldn't find an answer there before...

Comment: now I tried to increase the memory limit (1e+12) but it is still not working... I have just one object which has 556 kb so I really don't know what could suddenly be causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have many columns (k) and/or rows (n) in your input? The C code behind the `logistf::logistf.fit` function tries to allocate objects of size n*k and k*k.

Comment: You are aware that you can change the memory limit, but if you don't have additional physical RAM it won't help you?

Comment: the object has 379 rows and 257 columns, but also after getting rid of 20 variables it still gives the same error message - should I try to reduce even more? but again, it was working just fine before (and I hadn't added anything new)... similarly with my physical RAM - I already closed almost all other running programs and have about 8/16 gb free right now...can't imagine that this should be not enough? also restarting r did no help...

Comment: oh, you meant the input for the function? this has 5 variables and really, after removing two of them it works! but now that's still a problem cause I need all of them... and also before there were 5 variables and it worked?!

Comment: any idea anyone ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [reproducible questions in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A better formulated, and more specific, question is likely to get you more, and more more-useful, responses.